# HTML 5 website, doesnt fit the screen until you zoom in

Tags: html, css

I have created a website using HTML5, however, when you view it in a browser is does not fit the screen properly. When I zoom in, it fits perfect. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned width of body in your CSS? It will be better if you could place some lines of code here..